# In flutter, how can I register if the headset is suddenly unplugged

Tags: flutter, broadcastreceiver

Android [java offers to register a BroadcastReceiver checking for AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones#java), to listen to the system broadcasting an ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY message, when a sound is played but then the headset is unplugged or a Bluetooth device disconnected.

Is there a way to do this in flutter, to respond to the event that e.g. a headset is unplugged while playing sound?

---

With the hint in the answer below, I got this going, but only in DEBUG mode, not in a release ready APK. This is what I did:

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  public static final String STREAM = "XXX";
  public static String TAG = "player/java file";
  private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
  private BecomingNoisyReceiver myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver = null;


  private class BecomingNoisyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
final EventChannel.EventSink eventSink;

BecomingNoisyReceiver(EventChannel.EventSink eventSink){
  super();
  this.eventSink = eventSink;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Noisy Receiver activated");
    eventSink.success("success");

  }
}
}

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

  new EventChannel(getFlutterView(), STREAM).setStreamHandler(
          new EventChannel.StreamHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onListen(Object args, final EventChannel.EventSink events) {
                  Log.w(TAG, "adding listener");
                  myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver = new BecomingNoisyReceiver(events);
                  registerReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver, intentFilter);
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancel(Object args) {
                  Log.w(TAG, "cancelling listener");
                  unregisterReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver);
              }
          }
  );
  }  
}
```

And in Dart, in the class extending State:

```
static const platform = const EventChannel('XXX'); 
StreamSubscription _noisySubscription;
```

in initState():

```
 _noisySubscription = null;
```

Whenever I need it:

```
if(_noisySubscription == null){
    _noisySubscription = platform.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_handleNoisy);
      }
```

Whenever it needs to stop:

```
_noisySubscription.cancel().then((_){_noisySubscription = null;});
```

Any hint, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EventChannel](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html) to communicate an event on native part (Android) to Dart part. Ref: https://medium.com/@svenasse/flutter-event-channels-89623ce6c017

(Pseudo) Sample Code (it's not in runable state, but hopefully it gives you idea):

Dart part

```
void _handleNoisy(noisyEvent) {
  debugPrint("noisyEvent $noisyEvent");
}

static const stream =
    const EventChannel('com.yourcompany.yourapp/ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY');

StreamSubscription _noisySubscription = stream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_handleNoisy);
```

Java part

```java
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    public static final String STREAM = "com.yourcompany.yourapp/ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new EventChannel(getFlutterView(), STREAM).setStreamHandler(
                new EventChannel.StreamHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onListen(Object args, final EventChannel.EventSink dartEvents) {

                        Log.w(TAG, "adding listener");
                        noisyEvent = ... // Register
                        private class BecomingNoisyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                          @Override
                          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                              dartEvents.success("the payload you want to pass to dart")
                            }
                          }
                      }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(Object args) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "cancelling listener");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for accepting this answer. I would appreciate if you could upvote this as well.

Comment: Thank you @ TruongSinh!